# Glassfish says incomplete JoinColumns

Tags: glassfish, web-deployment

I used composit keys but I changed my mind and removed this kind of keys in my web application in NetBeans. But Glassfish says : the module has not been deployed, because of the invalid JoinColumns contents.

```
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field client] from the entity class [class x.ClientOrder] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
```

I have removed all of the tables from the DB, restarted the container, called the "Clean and Build" command to the project (it is succeed). But the EJB deployment fails. What should I do for the container forget the past?

The source code of entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "roleType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10 )
@NamedQuery( name=UserRole.QUERYNAME_GET_ROLE_BY_USERID_AND_TYPE, query = "SELECT ur FROM UserRole ur WHERE ur.userWR.id = :userID AND ur.roleType = :roleType" )
abstract public class UserRole implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public static final String QUERYNAME_GET_ROLE_BY_USERID_AND_TYPE = "userRole_getRoleByUserIDAndType";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String roleType;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
  private UserWithRoles userWR;

}


@Entity
@Data
@NamedQuery( name = Client.QUERYNAME_GET_ALL_CLIENTS, query="SELECT c FROM Client c" )
public abstract class Client extends UserRole
{
  public static final String QUERYNAME_GET_ALL_CLIENTS = "client_GetAllClients";

}


@Entity
@Data
@NamedQuery( name=ClientOrder.QUERYNAME_GET_CLIENT_ORDERS, query = "SELECT co FROM ClientOrder co WHERE co.client = :userID" )
public class ClientOrder implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public static final String QUERYNAME_GET_CLIENT_ORDERS = "clientOrders_getClientOrders";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private int id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
  private Client client;

  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "clientOrder" )
  private List<ClientOrderItem> orderItems;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. There was an error in the UserRole table. I have forgotten to remove the second @Id annotation on the userWR field. After I have removed it and rebuilt the app it deploys again.